# HTML5 spellcheck - any way to determine if a any misspelled words have been found

Tags: html, angularjs, spell-checking

I'd like to use the HTML5 spellcheck attribute to check for input typos. Using angularJS so would display an alert if the user tries to submit with typos. Is there any way to access some state that says if typos have been found in a text block.

Comment: Does this answer your question? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9390429/html5-spellcheck

Comment: No. I searched SO before posting.

Comment: @HandyManDan did you find a solution? Looking for the same thing.. Can be commercial solution.

Answer (score 1):

You can use this javaScript plugin:
https://www.javascriptspellcheck.com/

To use it you just need to unzip it and reference it. It also has a "Hello World" tutorial and well documented methods at their site.

The provided working example codes like this:

```
<script type='text/javascript' src='/JavaScriptSpellCheck/include.js' ></script>
<script type='text/javascript'>$Spelling.SpellCheckAsYouType('myTextArea')</script>
<textarea name="myTextArea"  id="myTextArea" cols="30" rows="4" style = 'max-width:500px;width:100%;height:200px;margin-bottom:20px'>
        This this is a simple exampl of Spell-checking As-You-Type using javascript spellcheck.
        It works in almost any browser, and supports upto 24 international languages.
        The button bellow shows an alternative way to spellcheck using javascript spellcheck - using a dialog iwndow!
</textarea>
<input type="button" value="Spell Check in a Dialog" onclick="$Spelling.SpellCheckInWindow('myTextArea')" />
```